# pandas - why the outputs of iloc and loc are different

Tags: python, pandas

```py
d1=df.loc[(df.Age<50) & (df.Age>10)]
d2=df[(df['Age']<50) & (df['Age']>10)]
d1 == d2
```

the output is:
[image]

and when i use loc and iloc to filter data, the outputs also different:

```py
d1.loc[[100]]
```

[image]

```py
d1.iloc[[100], :]
```

[image]

refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818001/8601639), Lev said `loc`include  the start and the stop index, so I tried this:

```py
d1.loc[[99], :]
```

[image]

but they are also different. Why?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`loc` filters the dataframe based on the index column. For example, when you are calling `df.loc[[100]]`, it will return the contents of the row with `index` value `100`. `iloc` filters the dataframe based on the location. `df.iloc[[100]]` will return `100th` row of your dataframe (numbering starts from `0`). If the index of `100th` row is `100`, then `df.iloc[[100]]` and `df.loc[[100]]` will return the same row.